# gitweb reports "404 - No projects found" on Ubuntu 14.04.2

Tags: git, ubuntu, gitolite, gitweb

I've looked through a bunch of other Qs & As here and haven't been able to figure this out yet...

Using Ubuntu 14.04.2, I have git + gitolite + gitweb right out of `apt-get`.

When I access /gitweb with by browser, it's running but it says `404 - No projects found`.

I moved the gitweb conf file from `/etc/apache2/conf.d` to the newer `/etc/apache2/conf-available` with symlink in conf-enabled, made the minor change to add + in front of FollowSymLinks.

**/etc/apache2/conf-available/gitweb.conf**:

```
Alias /gitweb /usr/share/gitweb

<Directory /usr/share/gitweb>
  Options +FollowSymLinks +ExecCGI
  AddHandler cgi-script .cgi
</Directory>
```

**/etc/gitweb.conf**:

```
<snip>
$projectroot = "/home/git/repositories/";
<snip>
$projects_list = "/home/git/projects.list";
<snip>
```

**gitolite.conf**:

```
repo    gitolite-admin
        RW+     =   tyrel

repo    testing
        RW+     =   @all

repo    myrepo
        RW+     =   tyrel
        R       =   gitweb daemon
```

gitolite us running as user git with group git. www-data is in the group git.

```
/home/git$ ls -l
total 8
-rw-r----- 1 git git   16 Mar 21 09:50 projects.list
drwxr----- 5 git git 4096 Mar 19 22:04 repositories
```

**.gitolite.rc**:

```
<snip>
$WEB_INTERFACE = "gitweb";
$REPO_UMASK = 0027;
<snip>
```

**projects.list**:

```
myrepo
```

And what's in the repositories:

```
/home/git$ sudo ls -l repositories
total 12
drwxr----- 7 git git 4096 Mar 21 09:50 myrepo.git
drwxr----- 8 git git 4096 Mar 21 09:50 gitolite-admin.git
drwxr----- 7 git git 4096 Mar 21 09:50 testing.git
```

What am I missing?

Thanks in advance for your help!

Answer (score 0):

I think the problem may be that all your directories (repositories, testing.git, myrepo.git) should also have execute group rights, e.g.

```
drwxr-x--- 5 git git 4096 Mar 19 22:04 repositories
```

I had a very similar problem when installing gitweb. Since the existing gitolite repos were created before updating UMASK in .gitolite.rc, they did not get the correct access rights and had to be adjusted manually. That was the reason I found your question.

This command executed in the gitolite directory should solve the problem:

```
find . -type d -exec chmod g+x {} \;
```

You probably already solved the problem somehow since the question is a bit old, but maybe someone else can use the answer.

Comment: Thanks for your response. I don't have this set up anymore to try out, but I "solved" it by using gitlab.com instead of hosting my own.